# Difficulty in using io.Pipe

Tags: go, io, pipe

Hi friends I want to write a data in a writer and pass it to a library using a reader so that it can read
Now the problem I have is that of png. Encode no longer continues and gets stuck there

```
r, w := io.Pipe()
err := png.Encode(w, img)
```

Tell me the solution if possible. Of course, I don't care if this problem is resolved, if you know another solution to the case that the data is written in a writer and read in a reader please suggest, there were secondary solutions, but I use two libraries that one just wants writer and one just reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w` is blocked waiting for a reader to read the data written to the pipe, thus blocking `Encode`

Reading from `r` will unblock `Encode` to the writer..

> each Write to the PipeWriter blocks until it has satisfied one or more
> Reads from the PipeReader that fully consume the written data